# Access an old commit in github

Tags: github, commit

I want to find commit `2a89985` in [this](https://github.com/Schischu/ptxdist_sh) Project in `Github`. I want to find out how to access a commit If I know the commit number? Since it is a big project there seems to be a lot of commits. Is it possible to access it from terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want web access to the commit without checking it out (like eedvinas.me suggested), you can access it directly by the url `https://github.com/<user>/<project>/commit/<full commit hash>`, e.g.: `https://github.com/Schischu/ptxdist_sh/commit/43135d7f4575a415dc7811bad540b3f0439a303f`.

However, the commit you're referencing, `2a89985`, does not exist in this project:

```
[amureini@amureini ptxdist_sh (master)]$ git show 2a89985
fatal: ambiguous argument '2a89985': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
[amureini@amureini ptxdist_sh (master)]$
```

Comment: sorry ya actually the link was wrong but with right link your method did work. I tried out `git show 2a89985` and it worked even `git log -p 2a89985` also worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout a specific commit:

```
git checkout 2a89985
```

This will put you in a detached head state though.

If you want to have a new branch on specific commit, then you can do it like this:

```
git branch branchname <sha1-of-commit>
```

In your case:

```
git branch newbranch 2a89985
```